# Почему margin-top двигает fixed блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

.block {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: #edd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Почему **.block** двигает **header** вместе с собой , он же не является его родителем ?

Comment: Потому что срабатывает схлопывание http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что нужно делать это паддингом или для родителя, или для того блока который надо подвинуть. Отступ высчитываеться в таком случае от елемента до родителя(при маржине), так как нету сверху от чего отталкиваться. Почитайте про свойство маржин, и про схлопывание отступов. +)

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
    


header {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background: #000;
}  



.block {
        
        padding-top: 40px;
        
        background: #edd;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="block"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что из-за схлопывания margin'ов сдвигается `body`, а у фиксированного блока не прописано, где ему рисоваться (`top: auto; left: auto;`), что означает, что он разместится в той позиции, в которой он бы оказался, если бы не был позиционированным - а это - начало body. Вот и двигается он вместе с ним. Как вариант, можно добавить ему `top: 0`.